# Getting ConcurrentModificationException with Kyro/Activiti and Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, activiti, spring-rabbit

I am trying out to integrate Activiti with Spring Integration. The sample provided by Josh Long works but when i try to change it, specifically MessageChannels part, it starts throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Josh Longs [Activiti/Spring Integration example](https://github.com/joshlong/activiti-examples) here.

As per Josh's code, MessageChannels is as follows:

```
@Configuration
class MessageChannels {

    @Bean
    DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    DirectChannel replies() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
}
```

I changed this to spring integration (With Stream Rabbit) to

```
@Configuration
public interface MessageChannels {

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel input();

    @Output("cooutput")
    MessageChannel createOutput();

}
```

And my property file contains,

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.cooutput.destination=outputChannel
```

I am getting following exception, when i am calling "/start".

```
2016-09-10 16:14:39.087  INFO 73606 --- [           main] c.e.ActivitiIntegrationDemoApplication   : Started ActivitiIntegrationDemoApplication in 8.236 seconds (JVM running for 8.759)
2016-09-10 16:15:39.524  INFO 73606 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-09-10 16:15:39.524  INFO 73606 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-09-10 16:15:39.540  INFO 73606 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 16 ms
2016-09-10 16:15:39.598  INFO 73606 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.codec.kryo.CompositeKryoRegistrar  : registering [40, java.io.File] with serializer org.springframework.integration.codec.kryo.FileSerializer
2016-09-10 16:15:39.638 ERROR 73606 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler@1b59052b]; nested exception is com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
Serialization trace:
classes (sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader)
beanClassLoader (org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster)
applicationEventMulticaster (org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext)
applicationContext (org.activiti.spring.ApplicationContextElResolver)
resolvers (org.activiti.engine.impl.javax.el.CompositeELResolver)
elResolver (org.activiti.engine.impl.el.ActivitiElContext)
cachedElContext (org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity)] with root cause

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.Vector$Itr.checkForComodification(Vector.java:1184) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.Vector$Itr.next(Vector.java:1137) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:92) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:552) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:518) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:552) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:518) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:552) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:518) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:552) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:518) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:552) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:518) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:552) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:518) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:552) ~[kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at
```

Also I have added following annotations to main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableBinding(MessageChannels.class)
```

Comment: Can you please share your complete use case. It's kind of hard to determine the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to help you, because your use-case is fully unclear, but you have problem with serialization for some unserializable object from the Activiti.
And looks like that one is `ActivityExecution` instance in the `execute()` method.

That Activiti-Spring Integration sample does something like this:

1. Start the process via `/start` REST endpoint.
2. That process make a delegation to the Spring Integration via `gateway` bean - `ReceiveTaskActivityBehavior`. It's JavaDocs says:

   ```
   * A receive task is a wait state that waits for the receival of some message.
   * 
   * Currently, the only message that is supported is the external trigger,
   * given by calling the {@link RuntimeService#signal(String)} operation.
   ```

So, that `execute()` impl just demonstrates that we can call Spring Integration. The main part remains the same - suspend the process until  `signal()` which is done by the `MessageChannels.replies()` from the `/resume` REST endpoint.

3. Now, explain, please, what you would like to achieve with the Spring Cloud Stream there. Actually both those `requests()/replies()` in this Activiti sample are `input`. You initiate something in the app via `/start` and `/resume` REST APIs.

Not sure how you have modified that sample, but that is really strange that `/start` initiates the message sending to the RabbitMQ Binder...

Comment: I am trying to build a POC where there will be 2 microservices in my application. When there is rest call, Activiti execution will start and will send message/object to second micro service in different tomcat. When second microservice done processing, it will send message back to Activiti module via rabbitmq and then Activiti will proceed to next processing. At this time, i have changed implementation and instead of sending executionMessage, i am sending String message and it works. For my POC this will work but not sure, whether i will need to send ActivitiExecution in Future.

Comment: I think that is the different story to determine how Activiti execution can travel through the network. If that is possible at all or make any sense finally. As for JBPM I know that I can use `processId` to retrieve a desired process from the share RDBMS.